# Using logstash, config server and eureka with spring cloud task and dataflow

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

We have an existing microservice environment with logstash, config and eureka servers. We are now setting up a Spring Cloud Dataflow (Kubernetes) environment (primarily intially to run tasks/batch jobs).

Ideally we would like the tasks to use the existing logstash, config and eureka servers via the standard spring boot configuration (annotations etc) to support the following scenarios:

**Logstash:** When a task runs its logs are output to logstash and viewable from Kibana

**Config Server:** To support changing configuration properties for tasks. eg a periodic task's configuration can be tweaked by altering the values on the configuration server and next time the task runs it will use the new values.
    My understanding is that config server properties will override properties in the task definition which override properties in the internal application.properties.

**Eureka:** Each task would register itself in Eureka. The main reason for this is that our tasks have web actuator endpoints exposed and we can then can use Spring Boot Admin (which can discover services via eureka) to access the actuator endpoints and information while a task is running. 
    (Some of our tasks can take hours to run and this would enable us to monitor them, adjust logging etc)

Is this a sensible approach - or are there any potential issues to look out for here (eg short lived tasks with eureka). I can’t find any discussion of this in the existing spring cloud data flow or spring cloud task documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You may try [logstash-logback-encoder](https://github.com/logstash/logstash-logback-encoder) for SCDF integration with ELK stack. It works fine for our SCDF on Yarn stream application.

Config Server should work for any Spring Boot application.